# Building list for capital city

Tags: age-of-empires-online

As the title says. Is there any list of buildings available to build in the capital city? Everything included decorations, random chest drops, workshops etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official one that I am aware of but [here](http://ageofempiresonline.wikia.com/wiki/Category:City_buildings) is the result of a concerted community effort to list every city building in the game. Hope this helps answer your question.